# Help undelete a question I've updated

Tags: support, specific-question, post-ban, vote-to-undelete

I've had a question ban for a while and I've touched up some of my questions. Yet, the ban still has not been lifted, probably due to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111873/comparing-a-char-value-against-a-char-value).

I've updated this question and think it makes a lot more sense now and have added a reproducible example. I don't have enough rep to undelete the question myself - could you guys take a look and help me out?

If it's not this question that's keeping me from the question ban, what is?

Comment: "If its not this question that's keeping me from the question ban, what is?" - unless you've only ever asked one question, there's several. Even old deleted ones count. I don't remember the exact criteria, but that's not the only reason for the ban

Comment: Your linked-to question could be further improved greatly by telling/showing what steps you've done to debug the code and isolate the error.

Comment: I also won't vote to reopen the question until it's improved further (at least until "not working" is explained) but I wouldn't downvote _this_ post either. Someone is trying to make an effort to improve their posts and is seeking guidance. I think we should encourage that.

Answer (score 15):

I've made a couple of superficial improvements to the grammar on [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111873/comparing-a-char-value-against-a-char-value), and undeleted it.

However, at this time, I'm *not* re-opening it, as the question still does not contain a sufficient description of what "not working" means. It is still just as eligible for closure today as it was before. **You haven't told us what, exactly is going wrong, and you haven't told us what, exactly, you expect.** Please review [the advice in the Help Center for how to ask debugging questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

As others have pointed out, [the question ban is a total quality score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) and is therefore not due to one specific question. You have three other deleted questions contributing to the question ban ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641915/how-do-i-make-a-game-in-visual-basic-like-zelda), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693782/how-do-i-go-to-a-certain-position-with-hscroller-in-vb), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112624/cant-find-value-of-string-contained-in-a-nested-structure-which-is-passed-by-poi)), but the first two look entirely unsalvageable to me, so they would be best left deleted.